# From Firoozbakht's conjecture to set interesting conjectures for sequences or series of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

In this post we denote the $k-th$ prime number as $p_k$. I present two conjectures, the first about the asymptotic behaviour of a product and the other about an alternating series. I don't know if these are in the literature. I think that these are interesting because involve the sequence of prime numbers and were an attempt to capture some aspect of the so-called *Firoozbakht's conjecture* and a conjecture from section **E7** of [1].

The interesting thing (and I assume that surely my creations/inventions failed in this, I believe that my sequences don't have enough precision to do it) should be try to create sequences, recurrences, products or series capturing the mathematical content of the mentioned Firoozbakht's conjecture, I say that the convergence or divergence of such objects is closely related to the veracity of Firoozbakht's conjecture.

**Conjecture 1.** One has that $$\prod_{n=1}^N\left(1+\frac{p_{n+1}^n}{p_{n}^{n+1}}\right)=O\left(N\log N\right)$$
as $N\to \infty$.

**Conjecture 2.** The series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n n\cdot \left(p_{n-1}\right)^{-\frac{n}{n-1}}$$
is a convergent series.

> **Question.** Can we refute any of previous conjectures? In other case, can be proved? In this last case provide hints or the proof to get the conjectures as propositions. **Many thanks.**

If you can/are able to set more precise conjectures, in the spirit of previous paragraphs, feel free add your comments or as remarks in your answer.

### References:

[1] Richard K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, Problem Books in Mathematics, Unsolved Problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Springer-Verlag (1994).

[2] See if you want the statement of Firoozbakht's conjecture [from this article of Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture)

Conjecture 30. The Firoozbakht Conjecture, from Carlos Rivera's web *The Prime Puzzles & Problems Connection* (August, 2012).

EDIT: Firoozbakht's conjecture is that if $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime, then for all $n\ge1$, $\root{n+1}\of{p_{n+1}}<\root n\of{p_n}$.

Comment: How hard would it have been to include a statement of Firoozbakht, instead of (or in addition to) a link to Wikipedia?

Comment: (1/2) Yes you are right, next time I should include it @GerryMyerson . I wrote a conjecture as a present for your patience and attention. I am inspired in Robin's equivalence to the Riemann hypothesis and the last identity of the linked Wikipedia in my post, if I am right it is the conjecture due to John W. Nicholson. *For each integer* $n>5040$ *one has that* $e^{\gamma}\sqrt{n}\log\left(n\left(\frac{p_{n}}{p_{n+1}}\right)^{n}\right)<\sigma(n)$. I had few computational evidence, thus I don't know if it is the best conjecture or if it is compatible with the theory.

Comment: (2/2) See also, if you want this line of code using Wolfram Alpha online calculator) `plot  sigma(n)-n^(5/8) e^(EulerGamma) log(n (prime(n)/prime(n+1))^n) , from n=5040 to 20000` As it was evoked I don't know if this last inequality has a good mathematical content. This is all, I hope you enjoy with the mathematics posted in the web MO and with this summer time.

Comment: I edited the conjecture in, since you couldn't be bothered to do it yourself. Also, it's Winter here.